# Copying items from one <asp:ListBox> to another dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is our code:

```
  <div>
 <table style="width: 349px">
    <tr>
    <td class="style1">
        <asp:ListBox ID="leftbox" runat="server" Height="114px" Width="212px" 
            SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:ListBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text=">>" onclick="Button1_Click" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="<<" onclick="Button2_Click" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:ListBox ID="rightbox" runat="server" Height="117px" Width="231px" 
            SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>
    </td>

    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The code behind is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> list= GetNameList();
        leftbox.DataSource = list;
        leftbox.DataBind();             
    }
}

private static List<string> GetNameList()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("keerthana");
    list.Add("sirisha");
    list.Add("anusha");
    list.Add("Anuradha");
    list.Add("Bhavani");
    list.Add("divya");
    list.Sort();
    return list;
}
```

Please tell me how to add two or more selected items one by one from `leftbox` to `rightbox`,  without using server-side code (as below):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (leftbox.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        rightbox.Items.Add(leftbox.SelectedItem.Text);
        leftbox.Items.Remove(leftbox.SelectedItem.Text);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Linq way of get selected items form ListBox

```
var selectedItems =  leftbox.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected).ToList();
```

then you can add all selected values to `rightbox` and finally remove from `leftbox`

### EDIT

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ListItem> selectedItems = new List<ListItem>();
    if (leftbox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < leftbox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (leftbox.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                    selectedItems.Add(leftbox.Items[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!rightbox.Items.Contains(selectedItems[i]))
            rightbox.Items.Add(selectedItems[i]);
        leftbox.Items.Remove(selectedItems[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please, tell me this using Generic list and nested-for loop

Comment: @user1469330 are you able to fix the issue?

Comment: yes, but actually we need to get it using nested for and by binding the generic list data to listboxes

Comment: Still we are unable to workout it using nested for loop and then binding generic list data to listboxes. please.. could u help us?

Answer (score 2):

Use client side javascript to do this, so you don't postback every time someone moves something, if you have jquery it can be as easy as:

```
$("#Button1").button().click(function() {
  $("#leftbox option:selected").each(function() {
      $("#rightbox").append(this);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please, tell me this using Generic list and nested-for loop

Answer (score 0):

this will do the work
but the problem here is..
after you transfer the item and click save button 
it will submit first before your save code will read
all the item you move to Leftbox from Rightbox will go back to Rightbox viseversa

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#left").bind("click", function () {
                    var options = $("[id*=RIghtBox] option:selected");
                    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                        var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                        $(options[i]).remove();
                        $("[id*=LeftBox]").append(opt);
                    } 
                });

                $("#right").bind("click", function () {
                    var options = $("[id*=LeftBox] option:selected");
                    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                        var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                        $(options[i]).remove();
                        $("[id*=RIghtBox]").append(opt);

                    }
                });
            });


        </script>
```